# Iterator Interface with abstract methods hasNext() and next()?

Tags: java

Iterator has a method ---> hasNext() which returns boolean value, it has next() which returns the element. 
Can anyone please tell if `Iterator` is an interface then how can it's abstract methods return the value ?? 
What's  the internal implementaion ?

Comment: Look at it. JDK includes the sources.

Comment: The iterators are often implemented as private classes. For example, in `ArrayList`, it is `private class Itr implements Iterator<E> {...}` and the `iterator()` method simply returns a new instance of `Itr`.

Comment: Yes, `iterator` is an interface and as such it doesn't implement the methods. The methods are provided by the concrete classes that implement the interface (ArrayList for instance, which has a private Iterator class). See this code for an example: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.Itr'

Answer (score 2):

Well, the implementation depends on how you obtain the Iterator object. For instance, if you have

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(); 
Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator();
```

you will get object of class `Itr`, which is a private class of `ArrayList`. Or for

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(); 
ListIterator<String> iterator = list.listIterator();
```

you will get object of `ListItr`. Similar things happen for `Set`. All you really need is look at the sources of JDK.

Answer (score 0):

Iterator is an interface and all java collection object has its own implementation (i.e. new IteratorType implementing Iterator  interface)  in class.

Comment: That's Ok, But could you Please give me  the  code where we are implementing the hasNext().

Answer (score 0):

An interface can be implemented by many different classes. It depends on which collection you called the `.iterator()` method which implementation you get.

If you create an iterator from an `ArrayList` for example I see (in Java 8) that the implementation is:

```
private class Itr implements Iterator<E> {
...
```

This class is an inner class of the ArrayList class. Other `Iterable` classes will provide other implementations of the `Iterator` interface.

Answer (score 0):

`Iterator` is an interface in Java. It is present in the `java.util` package as `java.util.Iterator`

When the `Iterator` is implemented by a class that is a subclass of the `Collection` interface which is in turn a extending the `Iterable` interface, we can get an `iterator()` object.

So the code looks like:

```
ArrayList a = new ArrayList();

  a.add("AA");
  a.add("BB");
  // Use iterator to display contents of a

  Iterator iterator = a.iterator();
  while(iterator.hasNext()) {
     Object element = iterator.next();
     ...
  }
```

So here we see that we are not directly using the `next()` or the `hasNext()` methods from the interface, rather we a using them by getting a `iterator()` object from the class that is implementing `Iterator` interface